# Redirect after download file with return response

Tags: javascript, python, django, redirect, response

I got a function to create a plain text in mi views.py:

```
def txt_file(data, headers):
    filename = datetime.datetime.now()
    content = ''

    for value in data:
        for key in headers:
            content += str(value[key]) + ";"
        content += ";;;;;;;;;;;;;\n"

    response = HttpResponse(content, content_type='text/plain')
    response['Content-Disposition'] = 'attachment; filename={0}'.format(filename)

    return response
```

This function is called from a button in the template, the file downloads ok, but I need that inmediatly after the download is complete, it redirect to a url.

***I already tried javascript document.location (but it executes the request too fast so the template reloads and the file gets lost, also tried a timeout but the download time it's relative so its not a solution.

It's there a way to do it?

Comment: As you can see there, the view returns a file as it's response, so the only way to then redirect is with javascript.

Comment: Indeed, but I tried the things mentioned in my post and they're not useful, is there other way to ?